# Reduce Memory Usage in React Native iOS App

Tags: ios, react-native

My app works perfectly fine in iphone7 , iphone 11 (real devices) , but crashes as soon as it navigates to another page in iphone6 and iphone XR. The error which i get from bugsnag is

> Out Of Memoryunknown method, The app was likely terminated by the
>   operating system while in the foreground

After going through the profile for memory leaks in Xcode i figured out 2 processes :

1.VM: ImageIO_PNG_Data was taking too much memory ~ 400 MiB

2.VM :CoreAnimation was taking too much memory. ~ 700 MiB

For image , i just resolved to lower quality images and the memory usage decreased, but in case of CoreAnimation does anyone have any idea how to lower the value in React-Native? Any suggestion would help. I've used react-navigation for navigating from one page to another.

Please check below image for your reference:

Do ask if any more information is required.

[image: Please check below image for your reference]

Comment: Hey! are u solve it?

Comment: hey @OliverD yah i was able to, the problem was the image which I've used, its pixel dimensions were 25k x 30k 
so it crashed on ios